# Razor syntax - ActionLink not showing correct links

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor-2, razorengine

I'm kinda struggling to get the action url in ASP.NET MVC4.

I am creating a link using below razor syntax:

```
@Html.ActionLink("some text", "Create", "Reports")
```

the output I get is:

```
<a href="/?action=Create&amp;controller=Reports">some text</a>
```

what I want is:

```
<a href="/Reports/Create">some text</a>
```

Any idea, what I am missing?

**UPDATE:**

RouteConfig is as below:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
     routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

     // ignoring .aspx, .asmx files  
     routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.aspx/{*pathInfo}");
     routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.asmx/{*pathInfo}");

     routes.MapPageRoute("DefaultRoute", string.Empty, "~/Default.aspx");
     routes.MapPageRoute("MapsRoute", "Map", "~/Default.aspx");

     routes.MapRoute(
              name: "Default",
              url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
              defaults: new { controller = "Reports", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
}
```

**2ND UPDATE**

if I comment following lines from route config, I get the URLs as expected. Any idea why?

```
routes.MapPageRoute("DefaultRoute", string.Empty, "~/Default.aspx");
routes.MapPageRoute("MapsRoute", "Map", "~/Default.aspx");
```

Comment: Could you show us how your routes are configured?

Comment: As rla4 suggests it may be a route issue, I think the issue is your routes. You have the correct syntax for the `ActionLink` helper.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 @Html.ActionLink("some text", "Create", "Reports",null,null)
```

Try to add in `route.config`

```
routes.MapPageRoute("DefaultRoute", "{def}", "~/Default.aspx"); 
routes.MapPageRoute("MapsRoute", "{map}", "~/Default.aspx");
```

Base class of [actionlink](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492124%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) as below:

```
public static MvcHtmlString ActionLink(
    this HtmlHelper htmlHelper,
    string linkText,
    string actionName,
    Object routeValues,
    Object htmlAttributes
)
```

Comment: ActionLink has many overloads..the syntax I had is correct.. ! anyways, this is not working.

Comment: It didn't work! Seems there is problem with using MapPageRoute , it mess up the ActionLinks? For now, I have added routes.IgnoreRoute(""); in the routes, so default page would redirect to Default.aspx.